# mvc 2 start date and end date validation

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi guys i'm trying to compare two dates, for some reason the following code will return false, if i specify 25/05/2012 (startdate) and 31/05/12 (end date).

This only happens if 25th is used as the start date, works fine if i use 26th.

```
 public bool IsValidDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return startDate < endDate && endDate > startDate;
    }
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: That code will not return false for the inputs you specified. Please show your real code, including the code that calls this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be mistaken something. For the given input you specified this code returns `true`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 5, 25);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 5, 31);
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidDate(startDate, endDate));
    }

    public static bool IsValidDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return startDate < endDate && endDate > startDate;
    }
}
```

Prints `true` on the console.

Now of course repeating the exact same condition twice is meaningless. Stating the condition once is more than enough:

```
public bool IsValidDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return startDate < endDate;
}
```

Comment: AH! i specified the date as DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012-05-25); instead of using the coma.

Comment: @RajuKumar - By using the dashes, the compiler actually interprets those as subtraction operators, and subtrackes 5 and then 25 from 2012, then passes the rsult to the single int constructor parameter of DateTime, which takes number of Ticks.  This would end up as a very old date.  And of course, 2012 minus 5 minus 25 is greater than 2012 minus 5 minus 30, even though in date math it would be greater.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make a function to check if `startDate < endDate`?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012 , 05 , 25);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2012 , 05 , 31);

    bool rtnval = IsValidDate(startDate, endDate);

}


public bool IsValidDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return startDate < endDate && endDate > startDate; 
}
```

this code returns true!!!

break it up and check you have the values you want

```
public bool IsValidDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    bool resulta = startDate < endDate; // break here
    bool resultb = endDate > startDate; // break here
    return startDate < endDate && endDate > startDate;
}
```

// oops i didn't realise its been answered already

Comment: `startDate < endDate` and `endDate > startDate` are the same statement, you are just adding extra code at that point.